# using var type in asp.net mvc list view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The following code does not compile

```
<ul>
<%
foreach( var row in SomeDataTable.Rows)
{
%>
  <li>
   <%= Html.ActionLink( row["field1"].ToString(), "action", new { } ) %>
  </li>
<%
}v
%>
</ul>
```

the error is - cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

var is supposed to be implicit type ?

What gives ?

NOTE - I *know* it is bad practice to use DataTable/Dataset as is etc etc so hold your horses on that one if you can please :)

Comment: sorry for the typo, fixed the variable name, on a small note - if it was item["field1"] as before, the error would be - the name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't it be `row["field1"]` and not `item["field1"]`?

Answer (score 2):

DataRowCollection does not implement IEnumberable<DataRow> only IEnumerable.  You will need to first call SomeDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>() in your foreach or not use var, as mxmissle suggests.

IEnumerable<DataRow> is required for the compiler to know what type is enumerated over, which is required for this use of var.

Comment: hmm, you could be right but not quite sure !
from what i understand ( & i could be wrong )
the var type is syntactic sugar and the compiler derives the type from the collection so therefore
if 
foreach(DataRow row in Table.Rows) compiles fine!
then the compiler should be able to deduce the type when using
foreach( var row in Table.Rows ) 

No ?

Or put it another way, is there something that would make it work with var - perhaps with System.Data.DatasetExtensions.dll - haven't poked around there yet, hoping someone can entice me :)

Comment: Kumar, yes it is syntactic sugar.  The problem here is that IEnumerable does not give the compiler enough info to determine what is coming out of Table.Rows.  In this case the var keyword is the same as foreach (object row in table.Rows)

It is for this reason that modern generic collections or lists all implement the IEnumerable&lt;T> interface.  I do not know why the DataRowCollection wasn't updated to support this.  It can be a little annoying

Comment: yet somehow the compiler works with
foreach( DataRow row in Table.Rows ) // compiles fine

Or is it possible that the use of var requires IEnumberable<T> as in
foreach(var row in Table.Rows ) // doesn't compile

which is really the question here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
row["field1"]
```

instead of

```
item["field1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have something to do w/ you calling item["field1"] but you named the iterator variable "row"?

Comment: no, in that case the error would be - the name 'item' does not exist in the current context

it's fixed however

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you cast it as a DataRow?

```
(DataRow row in SomeDataTable.Rows)
```